# Locating substring position in string

Tags: bash

Looking to extract the position of the third field, entered by the user, from the file "schemas.txt"

```
schemas="schemas.txt"
for i in ${schemas[@]};
do
    awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)if($i=="$3")print i}'
done
```

Any ideas as to why I'm stuck in an infinite loop here?

EDIT: Added an example below.

In schemas.txt, the second line is "People height weight age race occupation"

Assuming the user enters "age" as the their third parameter, I would like the line to be parsed and "4" to be returned as it is the fourth word in the string.

Comment: Sure you're in an infinite loop? Your terminal may seem to hang, as your `awk` reads from it not having an input file. Does it exit on <CTRL>-D? And, aside, the `i` shell variable is NOT the `i` within `awk`...

Comment: @RudiC, it does close on CTRL-D (usually I use CTRL-C to stop it), does this mean something specifically?

Comment: Yes, that means it reads from your terminal. Offer it a file.

Comment: @RudiC I'm sorry, but would the first `for` loop not be what I need to open a file? I was under the assumption that the `awk` statement would be searching each line of the schemas.txt file

Comment: Yes - if offered that file. The shell `for` loop just sets the `i` shell variable to the "schemas.txt" string as that's the only element of the `schemas` variable (which is not an array, btw), and then runs the `awk` script reading from terminal. Offer it a file, e.g `$i`, expanded to `schemas.txt`.

Comment: What position do you want? The line number where some value appears as the third field? Or something else? I'm not sure what "the position of the third field" means, surely it's always the third field, right? :) What should the user input?

Comment: @ilkkachu I added an edit to make my question a bit more clear.

Comment: @Conman, ah you mean `"$3"` as in the shell parameter, the third command line argument to the script? This can be a bit confusing since both the shell and awk use `$<number>` for somewhat similar but really different purposes...

Comment: @RudiC, so the awk statement is just searching "schemas.txt" as opposed to the entire file ?

Comment: @ilkkachu, yes exactly, I was spacing out a bit and forgot the term parameter and field seemed fitting at the time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got your intention right, I don't think you need the shell loop. Instead, give awk the name(s) of the file(s) to read on the command line. We can pass the keyword to look for with `-v`, it sets an awk variable from the command line.

So, for every line that contains 'age', this would print the field number(s) where it appears:

```
$ cat schemas.txt
People height weight age race occupation
age is first on this line
$ keyword=age
$ awk -vk="$keyword" '{ for (i = 1 ; i <= NF ; i++) if($i == k) print i }' schemas.txt 
4
1
```

Of course the fixed keyword is just for an example, you can use `awk -vk="$3"`, and skip the extra variable.

In general, that looks like it could be useful to print the line numbers too, you could use `print NR, i` to do that.

---

Here,

```
schemas="schemas.txt"
for i in ${schemas[@]};
do
    awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)if($i=="$3")print i}'
done
```

`schemas` only contains `schemas.txt`, so that's what the shell variable `i` gets set to in the loop. It's unused within the loop, though, so the loop doesn't really do much. The `i` in the awk script is independent from the shell `i`.

`awk` would seem to hang here, since by default it reads from stdin. Also, `"$3"` isn't expanded by the shell within the single quotes, so awk would look for a field literally containing `$3`.

The loop would make more sense with multiple files:

```
files=(file1.txt file2.txt)
for file in "${files[@]}"; do
    awk '{...}' "$file"
done
```

but even then you might as well pass all the files to awk in one go:

```
awk '{...}' "${files[@]}"
```

Comment: Thank you thank you thank you! Just trying to understand this a bit more, could you do the same command on a single line if you open the line first? 
Assuming $line contains the same line above
`keyword="$3"`
`echo $line | awk -vk="$keyword" '{ for (i = 1 ; i <= NF ; i++) if($i == k) print i }'`

Comment: @Conman, yees, but that would be slow, you'd run a copy of awk for each input line. See: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/169716/170373 . Also, use quotes around the variable, `echo "$line"`(https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/68694/170373). And yeah, `awk -vk="$3"` would work directly, I just used the extra variable since it felt clearer